# Why does apache redirect to www without RewriteRule

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

So I have a webserver running on Apache, with a few virtual hosts. I want to default to `https` and hence I have a rewrite rule.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName example.com
       ServerAlias example.com www.example.com
       RewriteEngine on
       ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
       RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L] 
</VirtualHost>
```

The interesting thing is that, I always see multiple 301 happening. ie
`http://example.com/something` -> `https://example.com/something` -> `https://www.example.com/something`

I thought it might be the `ServerAlias` that is causing the issue, so I split the conf to 2 separate rules

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName example.com
       RewriteEngine on
       ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
       RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L] 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName www.example.com
       RewriteEngine on
       ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
       RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L] 
</VirtualHost>
```

Still getting the same result. I don't have any rules anywhere to redirect to `www`, user enters example.com and without `www`, and I'm confused where does the second redirect come from.
I also don't have any `.htaccess` rules to perform redirects. What am I doing wrong here ?

Edit : Problem identified as a wordpress plugin doing the redirect. Thanks for hints from community.

Comment: Can we see the `VirtualHost` for port 443 - since that is where the redirect appears to be happening? You appear to only need one VirtualHost container for port 80, but the `ServerAlias` directive should only reference the _alias_, not the canonical ServerName as well. ie. `ServerAlias www.example.com`, not `ServerAlias example.com www.example.com` - although that's not the cause of your problem. Note that the directives above are all 302, yet you say you see multiple 301?

Comment: What kind of website are you running? Is it possible that the redirect is in the website code itself?

Comment: @w3dk Thanks for the hint. We had a wordpress installation with some plugins to do the redirect. I wish to upvote above comment, but not enough credits to do that. Thanks again!

Comment: I've added an answer you can accept (removes question from unanswered queue). You'll need 15+ rep before you can upvote unfortunately. Just curious... you are running WordPress without "pretty" URLs (ie. no mod_rewrite in .htaccess or server config)?

Comment: I don't do the content development (done by another person) and was completely unaware of the wordpress settings etc. We do have the mod_rewrite enabled. And .htaccess does make some rewrites, but not performing redirects to www etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the redirect, it looks like this could be happening in the `VirtualHost` container for port 443.

Failing that, the redirect could be happening in the website code itself. (Which appears to be the case here - a WordPress plugin).